# Clicking ListView item and displaying its database contents in another activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm making a simple notes app which allows users to save data to a firebase database, ive then retrieve this data in a separate activity in a ListView and made each item within this ListView clickable. Would anyone be able to assist me in loading this data back into the original activity (with edit texts where we originally wrote this data).

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: First replace `String contentTest = getIntent().getStringExtra("titleTest");` with `String contentTest = getIntent().getStringExtra("contentTest");` and be more clear what actual issue you are facing.

Comment: Hi guys apologies, I have uploaded pictures of the app and tried to explain a bit better, hopefully it makes my issue clearer, I wish to click on an item in the ListView which will reopen acitivty 1 with its data in it

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake while putting data to your new intent
You need to replace

```
DatabaseReference putData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ProgressReports/" + uid + "/" + id.get(i));
            Intent intent = new Intent(list_view.this, ProgressReports.class);
            String title = String.valueOf(putData.child("title"));
            String content = String.valueOf(putData.child("content"));
            intent().putExtra("titleTest", String.valueOf(title));
            intent().putExtra("contentTest", String.valueOf(content));
            startActivity(intent);
```

With

```
DatabaseReference putData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ProgressReports/" + uid + "/" + id.get(i));
        Intent intent = new Intent(list_view.this, ProgressReports.class);
        String title = putData.child("title").getValue(String.class);
        String content = putData.child("content").getValue(String.class);
        intent.putExtra("titleTest", title);
        intent.putExtra("contentTest", content);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks Vikash, now it is bringing across the URL link to the database as opposed to the actual data within it, any advice? thanks for this so far

Comment: @L Thompson, I have modified my answer, and now your code should work fine, just follow the answer modified. :)